# need to write htaccess rule for directory pages

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am wondering if there is any way to do this;

If any page is not available in /x2/ directory then it will load same name page from /y2/  without changing the display url.

display url -> abc.com/x2/pen.html 
fetch page -> abc.com/y2/pen.html

here page extension is also being rewritten in both directories means .html extension is loading existing .php page content.

Pls let me know if this is possible and how?

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside `/x2/` directory create this .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) /y2/$1 [L]
```